# How to fix this 'NameError' problem in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning to deal with function in `Python 3.6` now. I try to set a function to count the number of times a specific word appears in a text file, but I face the `NameError` problem.

I tried the tool on `pythontutor.com` to visualise the steps of my code to find out why. It seems like the value of `count_num` in function `count_word` doesn't get pass to the for loop. But I really don't understand why.

```
filenames = [
    "The Wallypug in London.txt", 
    "Chats on Old Silver.txt", 
    "Jack Jingle, and Sucky Shingle.txt", 
    "Superstition and Force.txt"
]


def count_word(filename, word):
    with open(filename) as open_file:
        file_content = open_file.read()

    count_num = file_content.lower().count(word)
    return count_num


for filename in filenames:
    count_word(filename, "great")
    print('There are ' + str(count_num) + " 'great' in " + filename + ".")
```

I expect the output would be "There are 89 'great' in The Wallypug in London.txt. But it just returns,

```
NameError: name 'count_num' is not defined
```

Comment: You never assign the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the assignment in this line

```
    count_word(filename, "great")
```

Change to

```
    count_num = count_word(filename, "great")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help :

```
filenames = [
    "The Wallypug in London.txt", 
    "Chats on Old Silver.txt", 
    "Jack Jingle, and Sucky Shingle.txt", 
    "Superstition and Force.txt"
]

count_num ="" #define count_num here
def count_word(filename, word):
    count_num=0
    return count_num


for filename in filenames:
    count_word(filename, "great")
    print('There are ' + str(count_num) + " 'great' in " + filename + ".")
```

Comment: I'd rather assign the result of `count_word(filename, "great")` to a variable than manipulating a global value that is not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `count_num` in function `count_word` is a local variable, and cannot be referenced in global area.
Replace `count_word(filename, "great")` with `count_num = count_word(filename, "great")`